# Powerapps - When i open the screen1 i need the radio1 option to not select either radio button

Tags: powerapps

When i open a form called screen1,  i need the radio1  option to not select either radio button.

I have 2 options on the radio1   "Override" and "ByPass".

I have tried setting the default value( for form screen1) to  = radio1.default  = "No Value" but it does not work ?

Answer (score 1):

If your control is not part of the 'Form' or 'Gallery' control,
 try to [reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-reset) the control on 'on visble' property of the screen

You cannot reset controls that are within a Gallery or Edit form control from outside those controls. You can reset controls from formulas on controls within the same gallery or form.

Comment: @David Powell Can you mark this as answer if this helps?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the Form `DefaultMode` property is set to `New`
2. Set the `Default` property of the Radio Button to `Blank()`
3. Set the `Reset` property of the Radio Button to `varReset`
4. `OnVisible` of the Screen, add the following:

```
    Set(varReset, true);
    Set(varReset, false);
    Set(varReset, true)
```

**BONUS**:

- Place your Radio Button action code under the `OnSelect` property rather than `OnChange`
- Believe it or not, Radio Buttons (and Toggles) actually "move" when they reset.
- This state change will trigger your `OnChange` code!